# What is real meanning of Prathipathi poojawa?

Tags: the-buddha

I know best poojawa is **prathipathi poojawa**. Does it mean follow the Lord Buddha's instructions? However what is a depth meaning of it? And how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means to honor the Buddha by working on purifying the mind and attaining freedom from suffering as he instructed.